# Hashing the device id into a 64 bit (or greater) then convert that into base-31 [iOS]

Tags: ios, objective-c, hash, long-integer

I am having trouble hashing my device's id into a 64 bit (or greater) representation and then converting that into a base-31 representation. Any one have any tips or guidance? I have been looking online and can't seem to find much.

Each base-31 digit should then be represented by the this list: `2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 A B C D E F G H J K M N P Q R S T U V W X Y Z`

What I've tried:

```
NSString *myID = [[[UIDevice currentDevice] identifierForVendor]UUIDString];
NSLog(@"Non Hash: %@", myID); //Logs the 36 character string
myID = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu",(unsigned long)[myID hash]]; // Changed thanks to rokjarc
NSLog(@"Hash: %@", myID); //Logs same 36 character string


//Logs 36 character string
NSLog(@"UUIDString: %@", [[[UIDevice currentDevice] identifierForVendor] UUIDString]);

//Logs out a 10 character numeric value
NSLog(@"Hash: %lu", (unsigned long)[[[[UIDevice currentDevice] identifierForVendor] UUIDString] hash]);

//Logs out a 2 character numeric value
NSLog(@"LongLong: %lld", [[[[UIDevice currentDevice] identifierForVendor] UUIDString] longLongValue]);
```

Comment: use `myID = [myID hash];` - this method does not modify the string it self - it returns the hash of the string...

Comment: @rokjarc Good catch! It's actually `myID = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu",(unsigned long)[myID hash]]` because you are converting from NSUInteger to NSString. Any Idea how to convert that into a base-31 12 digit string? Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you restrict the problem to a 64 bit integer it is not difficult. Basically keep dividing the number by 31 and accumulate the remainders into a string. For numbers larger than will fit into an integer things get more complicated. Either use a big integer math package.

Comment: @Zaph I am trying to restrict it to a 64 bit integer. How do I do that? I keep seeing that not all iPhone/iPads are 64 bit, so how do I for the UDID to come out as 64 bit and then convert it into a base-31 that is 12 digits long. What is the size that NSInteger or int allows?

Comment: Simply: [hashing the id](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000154-hash) returns unsigned integer - this integer is within the limits of 64-bits. So `NSUInteger hash = [myID hash];` and from here on you can follow one of the provided answers...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[[[UIDevice currentDevice] identifierForVendor]UUIDString]` returns a UUID which is comprised of 32 hex characters which is 128 bits. 12 base31 characters can only represent 63 bits. Thus the entire UUID can not be represented.

Best bet is to run the UUID through SHA (which seems to be what `[myID hash]` does) and convert 63 of the bits of that into 12 base31 characters.

The reason for the hash function (SHA) is to remove any pattern in the UUID, each bit in the result of SHA is equally likely to be a 1 or 0.

Notes:
31^12 = 7.87E17 and 2^64 = 1.84E19
thus a 64 bit number can not be represented in 12 base 31 characters. 63 bit can however.

Base32 is a **lot** simpler than base31 for values larger than 64 bits.

Here is a code sample that creates a string of base31 characters from a 64-bit integer:

```
uint64_t uid = 14467240737094581;

NSString *baseCharacters = @"23456789ABCDEFGHJKMNPQRSTUVWXYZ";
NSUInteger base = baseCharacters.length;
NSMutableString *baseString = [NSMutableString new];
while (baseString.length < 12) {
    uint64_t remainder = uid % base;
    uid /= base;
    NSString *baseCharacter = [baseCharacters substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(remainder, 1)];
    [baseString insertString:baseCharacter atIndex:0];
}
NSLog(@"baseString: %@", baseString);
```

NSLog output:
baseString: 2KP7MAR5CX86

Comment: Amazing! Thank you. I was working on something last night and your code looks much much cleaner and clearer. Thanks a lot!